# How to non-destructively test file-detection functionality

Tags: testing, theming

I am writing tests for a module that is dependant on an external library, located in:

```
sites/all/libraries/mylib
```

I have written a hook_requirements to check for the presence of this library and display it in the site status report.

However, I cannot find information or documentation about testing for the presence/absence of external files reliably. The verbose run of my test currently shows that it detects the file in my sites libraries folder.

Right now I am playing around with workarounds like moving the contents of mylib during the test setup call but that seems problematic to me because of the potential issues if tests are not completed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have this idea - maybe use [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries)? It seems they already did the job you are struggling with. `libraries_detect($name)` works. It's tested and proven. Why would you need to reinvent the wheel? ;)

Comment: I am using libraries API. My issue is merely that I want to make sure that my hook_requirements works. Meaning I want it to give me an error when the library is absent. The testing environment does not create a new sites/all/libraries folder - it uses the existing drupal install instead. So I am trying to find a way to test that detection.